# gganimate doesn't always show geom_rect elements but adds values which don't exist in original data

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, data-visualization, gganimate

Here is a `dump`ed sample dataset:

```r
sample_data <-
structure(list(
  user_id = c("E", "T", "B", "R", "I", "L", "Z", "M", "W", "A"),
  month = structure(c(17836, 17956, 17683, 17622, 18017, 17318, 17471, 17928, 17987, 18017), class = "Date"),
  value_foo = c(92.68, 98.5, 36.82, 64.58, 36.59, 81.86, 64.99, 59.14, 78.41, 63.4), 
  value_bar = c(3.28, 4.17, 730.25, NA, 2971.95, 12.2, 3.85, 14.14, 40.69, 21.67)
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Note that each user_id has only one row. If I make a static plot, where x and y are value_bar and value_foo respectively, it looks like this:

```r
g <- ggplot(sample_data, aes(value_bar, value_foo)) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 30, ymin = 60, ymax = Inf, fill = "green", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 30, ymin = 45, ymax = 60, fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = 30, ymin = 30, ymax = 45, fill = "orange", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 30, xmax = 300, ymin = 60, ymax = Inf, fill = "yellow", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 300, xmax = Inf, ymin = 60, ymax = Inf, fill = "orange", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 30, xmax = 300, ymin = 45, ymax = 60, fill = "orange", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 300, xmax = Inf, ymin = 45, ymax = 60, fill = "red", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = 30, xmax = Inf, ymin = 30, ymax = 45, fill = "red", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_rect(xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, ymin = -Inf, ymax = 30, fill = "red", alpha = 0.05) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label(aes(label = user_id), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 50)
g
```

[image]

Now, I want to make it animated, and each frame represents a unique month. (I know it may seem unnecessary here, but my real dataset includes longitudinal data from 4000+ people.) I used `gganimate` package and followed [its provided example](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate#yet-another-example) to do it:

```r
p <- g +
  transition_time(month) +
  labs(title = "{frame_time}")
animate(p, fps = 2)
```

[image]

*Now this is not what I expected.* The problems include:

1. The colored rectangles are missing in most of the frames.
2. Data points from the same user show up in multiple frames, moving. Those don't exist in the given data.
3. The frames don't proceed on monthly basis though my month column has only dates of the 1st days of months.

I want an animation where

1. Colored rectangles stay in every frame as the fixed background.
2. Data show up only when they come from the original dataset.
3. Each frame represents a month.

How should I do it right? And why doesn't my solution work? Thanks.